# From how far away are the navigation lights of a large airliner typically visible?

Tags: visibility

I live about 22 miles away from one international airport in the UK, and just over 30 miles away from another.

When I spot aircraft lights at night and check for corresponding aircraft on flightradar, I'm surprised to see that they seem to belong to aircraft making approaches to land at these airports - which got me thinking - on a clear night, from how far away are a large aircraft's navigation lights typically visible? (I'd be interested in answers relating to distance when viewed from the ground and in the air).